# How to detect malicious XML/JSON payloads?

Tags: java, json, xml, security

I'm currently trying to implement a threat protection mechanism in Java for web applications which uses xml/json payloads.

I want to know that, is there any ways/libraries to detect,

- Length of xml/json elements
- Depth of xml/json documents
- Length of attributes
- Attribute count per element

In addition to that, I have to do those without parsing the document because if we parse the document, a malicious xml/json document can attack the parser. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't get any of these metrics without parsing. So what you're actually looking for is a parser that imposes user-specified limits. I don't think such a parser exists, but of course there are open source parsers that you could modify.

Comment: @MichaelKay well thanks for your insights Michael. I'll look into somelibraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java applications using XML libraries are particularly vulnerable to XXE because the default settings for most Java XML parsers is to have XXE enabled. To use these parsers safely, you have to explicitly disable XXE in the parser you use. This link below might help you.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Java